# Compare (string) contents from 2 arrays

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have 2 arrays which each of them contain different strings. I want to compare strings from those 2 and display matched strings only.

for instance, if words array has list of words = "wolf", "Wolfachite", "Wolfberry", "Wolf"

and if names array has list of words = "Winnie", "Wolf", "Wolfgang"

it would display "wolf".

sadly, I am confused which steps I must take to compare those two.

```
  NSString *nameString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/usr/share/dict/propernames"
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                        error:NULL];

    NSString *wordString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/usr/share/dict/words"
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                        error:NULL];

  //Fill it into array

    NSArray *names = [nameString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    NSArray *words = [wordString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code it compares your string

```
for (int i=0; i<[names count]; i++)
{
    NSString *strNames = [[names objectAtIndex:i] uppercaseString];

    for (int j=0; j<[words count]; j++)
    {
         NSString *strWords =  [[words objectAtIndex:j] uppercaseString];

        if ([strNames isEqualToString:strWords])
        {
            //your code when condition satisfied
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here is another way I found in web

for (NSString *n in words) {
            if ([names containsObject:n]) {
                NSLog(@"%@ is a duplicate. ",n);
                count++;
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

A good option would be to use [`-[NSMutableSet intersectSet:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableSet/intersectSet:) but note that this compares the strings using `isEqual:` — if you want a case-insensitive or diacritic-insensitive search then you will need to use your own custom objects and implement `-isEqual:` and `-hash`.